# Bash array not working providing expected length

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get all jar files in a directory and store them in an array. Currently, it's not working as expected and I think it's because it's an array inside an array? Let me know if it is and how would I fix it. When I echo the length of the array, it's always 1 yet when I loop over it, it can have more than 1 file.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/home/ubuntu/RLCraft" || exit 1
jars=("$(ls *.jar)")
echo "${#jars[@]}" -gt "1"
if (("${#jars[@]}" > "1")); then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
for i in "${jars[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
if [ "${#jars[@]}" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Choose a server jar:"
    for i in "${jars[@]}"; do
        echo "$i"
    done
    read -r serverJar
else
    serverJar="${jars[0]}"
fi
```

Expected output:

```
yes
magma-server.jar
minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar
```

Resulting output:

```
no
magma-server.jar
minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar
```

Comment: once you've populated the array try running `typeset -p jars` to see what's in the array; does the array contain what you think it should contain?

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [Useless \[and often wrong\] Use of ls *](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill an array from all `.jar` files just do:

```sh
array=(*.jar)
```

Here is your fixed script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

cd "/home/ubuntu/RLCraft" || exit 1

jars=(*.jar)

if [ "${#jars[@]}" -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "Choose a server jar:"
  selections=("${jars[@]}" 'Quit')
  select serverJar in "${selections[@]}"; do
    case $serverJar in
      '')
        echo "Invalid choice" >&2
        ;;
      'Quit')
        echo "Goodby!"
        exit
        ;;
      *)
        echo "You have selected: $serverJar"
        break
        ;;
    esac
  done
else
  echo "No jar found in $PWD" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Would just like to note that this script returns the following, https://imgur.com/a/VysKD3Y. Otherwise, it works :D

Comment: @SamuelCorsi-House enter the number from the selection :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is while creating the array.

```
jars=("$(ls *.jar)")
```

When you do this, the quotes is causing the whole list to be interpreted as one single element. Remove the quotes as below to resolve the issue:

```
jars=($(ls *.jar))
```

Edit:

As mentioned in comments a better way is without the ls as

```sh
jars=(*.jar)
```

Comment: You don't fill an array with ls

Comment: @LéaGris can you help understand why that's a bad practice?

Comment: Because `jars=(*.jar)` does the same thing without spawning ls, and keeps spaces in filenames intact.

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail.